# Cannot access print queue - Server side printing vs Local printing

Tags: printing, printer, webserver, network-printer

Scenario :

User works on a desk top that is locally configured and connected to Printer ‘A’. Any print given directly from the desk top like a word doc or email or a web page, prompts the printer dialog, Printer A is selected, and print queue on that printer can be easily managed from the desktop directly (right click printer icon in system tray or going to Device and printers from start menu)

Likewise, there is a web server X that is linked/configured to same printer A. The user from the desk top, now uses a web application (hosted on the web server X) and there is a 'print feature' in the web application. User selects (checkboxes) couple of documents and clicks on Print button (printer A). The print button executes server side printing code. The printing happens on the server. When I log in to the server and open the printer A queue, I can see the print jobs. But the user cannot see the same queue from the desk top printer A queue.

Why is that ? what do I need to do to give the user access to printer queue irrespective of where the print job originated from (desktop or server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is that ?

If, as described, the web app is doing server-side printing, then the print job never involves the user's local print queue; therefore it doesn't show any information about the print job in the user's queue.

> what do I need to do to give the user access to printer queue irrespective of where the print job originated from (desktop or server)

You would need to give them permission to view/control the print queue on the server.  Exactly how you would do this depends greatly on your network setup, of which we're not aware.

Assuming Windows, that the user is on a LAN with the server, that the printer on the server is shared with the user, and that they have permission to access/see the printers queue, they should be able to simply head to `\\<servername>\Printers` to see a list of remote printers on the server, and then view the printer's queue by double-clicking the printer's icon.